# Why do chromedriver_autoinstaller not working in python selenium?

Tags: python

recently i noticed when downloading chromedriver that chrome has different way after version 114 to download chromedriver, then I got autoinstaller function is not working, it is considered as useless in code and i got the error that chromedriver is not found in the path.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import os
import time

import chromedriver_autoinstaller
chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
```

I tried to use alternative functions but useless.